# Forbidden response when trying to access putmapping url

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, postman

I try to make an update of a record in controller using PutMapping and I use spring-security also. I don't know why it shows forbidden as I mentioned `access("permitAll")` while setting `httpSecurity` object.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
    .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/home").hasAuthority("USER")
      .antMatchers("/username").authenticated()
      .antMatchers("/testAdmin").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/updateLocation/**").access("permitAll")
      .antMatchers("/","/**").access("permitAll")
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
    /* ... */
}


// in controller:
@Data
class UpdateUserLocation{
    private double lat;
    private double lng;
}
//@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8085")
@PutMapping(path="/updateLocation/{userId}", consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, produces= {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
UserLocations updateUserLocation(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody UpdateUserLocation usr) {
    UserLocations usrLoc = userLocRepo.findByUser_id(id);
    System.out.println("Usr loc:" + usrLoc.getId() + " " + usrLoc.getLat()+","+usrLoc.getLng());
    usrLoc.setLat(usr.getLat());
    usrLoc.setLng(usr.getLng());
    userLocRepo.saveAndFlush(usrLoc);
    return usrLoc;
}
```

In postman I use my link:
`localhost/updateLocation/2`

 where 2 - represent the id for the object I want to update
and in body I added:
`{
    "lat" : "47.2",
    "lng" : "27.9"
}`

And I get this response:
`{
    "timestamp": "2019-08-22T13:56:09.189+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/updateLocation/2"
}`

Comment: still not working, it shows forbidden too :(

Comment: I don't have a base mapping for my controller

Comment: @ViorelCasapu You didn't send the CSRF token. You have to send the token in your request.

Comment: @danilo still the same problem

Comment: @dur how can I do that? (I didn't find anything understandable)

Comment: @dur I disabled csrf in configure() and that worked, but I don't think it's ok to disable it. Can you hint how to send csrf token in postman?

Answer (score -1):

Use antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/updateLocation/*") instead of antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/updateLocation/**").

Remove one asterisk.

Comment: still the same problem